# How to change the text gravity on alertdialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, gravity

I've been searching for a while and I haven't found the solution to this problem of mine yet, I have a alertdialog with a few items [(Here it is)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXiJI.png)

But as you can see, the text is aligned to the left. Is there a way to align the items text to the center?

Here's a bit of my code

```
 chosenItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // setup the alert builder
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setTitle("Choose a category");
                // add a list
                String[] items = {"Hey", "stack", "overflow", "please", "help", "Medical", "Ammo"};
                //  String[] items = {"Weapons", "Tools", "Items", "Clothing", "Components", "Medical", "Ammo"};

                builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which) {
                            case 0:
                                reciclador(3, rSlotFrame, rSlotText, rSlotProbabilidade, 30, 50, 1, 0, 100, 100, 100, 0, "cloth_icon", "metalfrags_icon", "sewingkit_icon", "");
                                break;
                            case 1:

                            case 2:

                            case 3:

                            case 4:

                            case 5:

                            case 6:

                        }
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
                dialog.getWindow().setLayout(800, 700);
            }
        });

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show you code for alert dialog

Comment: Post your dialogue's xml

Comment: @NileshRathod Just did!

Comment: @VishalVaishnav I added the code to the question

Comment: easiest way to use custom Dialog

Comment: Title is not centralized too. You must create custom XML for dialog. Check this, I've created one a few months ago: https://github.com/lugrugzo/JustBrowser/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/browser/ui/dialog/JListDialog.java

Comment: best way  : Create your custom layout and add it to dialog

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom objects in AlertDialog list; how to get a display string and then the actual value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811117/custom-objects-in-alertdialog-list-how-to-get-a-display-string-and-then-the-act)

Answer (score 1):

**you can use custom dialog for that like this create a custom layout like this**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical">

     <TextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:padding="10dp"
       android:text="title"
       android:textColor="#000" />

     <TextView
      android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:padding="10dp"
      android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text " />


    <TextView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:padding="10dp"
     android:text="description" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**now create custom dailog llike below code**

```
 final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(LoginActivity.this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_layout);
Textview tvTitle;
tvTitle = (Textview) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
Window window = dialog.getWindow();
window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
window.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);

tvTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
       // perform your action here 
    }
});
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find AlertDialog Title view by this code and set gravity manual but first you must create a AlertDialogBuilder and one Alert dialog like in code

```
    MaterialAlertDialogBuilder dialogBuilder = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this);
    dialogBuilder
    .
    .
    .
    AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
        LinearLayout titleTemplate = alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.title_template);
    titleTemplate.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
```

You can find all view in alert_dialog.xml and find in code and use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom view in `AlertDialog`.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);
View alertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog, null, false);
alertDialog.setView(alertView);
```

Add your custom requirement of your text in your layout file.

From [documenation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html):

> If you want a custom layout in a dialog, create a layout and add it to an AlertDialog by calling setView() on your AlertDialog.Builder object.

Comment: This did work somehow, but I can't change the items color, gravity, etc. I'm only able to set a whole new layout to the alertDialog.

Comment: You have to define text color, gravity in layout file of relative field.

Answer (score 0):

you need to apply theme for the dialog on the initial state

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog(context, R.theme.DialogTheme);
```

and declare theme in your theme.xml or styles.xml

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="Animation.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/DialogTextAppear</item>

</style>

<style name="DialogTextAppear" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```